# Why doesn't my javascript work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create javascript that will count from 1 to 1000 and push any multiples of 3, 5 into an array called multiples then print that array out using console.log(). For some reason my code isn't working. Does anyone know why?

```
var n; 
var multiples = [];

for(n = 1; n <= 1000; n += 1) {
    console.log("Counting");
}

if(n % 3 === 0) { 
    n.push(multiples);
}
else {
}

if(n % 5 === 0) {
    n.push(multiples);
}
else {
}

if(n >= 1000) {
    console.log(multiples);
}
else {
}
```

Comment: Now that I reformatted **your** code, do you still have any questions?

Comment: Thank you for reformatting it. Not anymore. Travis J solved all my problems. Thanks for teaching me.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code. Using `{}` in your for block designates the scope of the code executing in each iteration. So in order to access each value for `n` you need to be placing your conditional statements inside of the `{}` and not outside of them.

There is a slight syntax error with your multiples array. In order to push a value into an array you would use the arrayname followed by the dot operator and then the push function with the argument being the value pushed. In terms of multiples and n, this means `multiples.push(n)`.

When using an `if()` block, else is not required.

It is generally best practice to include the variable declaration inside of for loops, and also to use ++ as opposed to += 1.

Overall, your code would need to look more like this

```
var multiples = [];

console.log("Counting");
for(var n = 1; n <= 1000; n++) {
    if(n % 3 === 0) { 
        multiples.push(n);
    }
    if(n % 5 === 0) {
        multiples.push(n);
   }
}
console.log(multiples);
```